# Content info of 'row' in ( E.g for index, row in df.iterrows() ) for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops

There is this code commonly used in python pandas "`for index, row in df.iterrows()`".

What is the difference between displaying these during the loop:

```
print(row) 
print(row.index)
print(row.index[index])
print(row[index])
```

I tried printing them and cant comprehend what it does and how it selects the content and I cant find a well explained source online.

Answer (score 0):

For one, it's more concise.

Secondly, you're only supposed to use it for displaying data rather than modifying. According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) you may get unpredictable results (a concurrent modification thing, methinks).

As to how it selects it, the docs also say it just returns the individual rows as `pd.Series` with the index being the id pandas uses to keep track of each row in the `pd.DataFrame`. I'd guess it'd be a akin to using a python `zip()` function on a list of `int` [0..n] and a list of `pd.Series`.